# Как из модуля ядра очистить сокет от данных имея указатель на struct socket?

Tags: linux, сокет, kernel

В модуле ядра получаем указатель на структуру struct socket *sock.

Как корректно очистить данный сокет от накопившихся входных данных?

PS: Некоторые приложения недостаточно торопливо читают данные

Comment: А что читающее приложение скажет, когда у него не окажется куска данных в середине потока. Оно же скорее всего заглючит.

Comment: Пусть заглючит приложение, нежели ядро :) Такая ситуация может иметь место, если пакеты потеряются, что допустимо и приложениям следует это учитывать.

Comment: А почему ядро должно заглючить. У вас какой размер буфера ? копать в сторону SO_RCVBUF. Ядро не будет принимать даные из сети если уже заполнило буфер указанного размера и при этом корректно сообщит посылающей стороне, что слать пока больше не надо (послав окно 0 размера)

Comment: Хотя это конечно TCP касается ... с UDP сложнее, но думаю ядро это должно учитывать и то же иметь предельный размер

Comment: в сокете застревают структуры модуля, их надо при выгрузке модуля зачистить, отсюда и задача.

Comment: А приложение после выгрузки модуля что будет получать через этот сокет в котором были "структуры модуля". Мне почему то кажется, что сокет надо закрывать. А вообще вам просто надо посмотреть исходники ядра касательно того вида сокетов которые вы используете. Например ipv4\tcp.c, предсказуемо, при закрытии сокета удаляет все skb вот такие куски и можно брать к себе в модуль

Comment: @Mike Приложение уже ничего не получит после выгрузки модуля.

Comment: тогда точно закрывать сокет и все. готовые функции закрытия в ядре проще найти.